# MySQL Filter certain values from a column containing different data types

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, merge, sql-like

There are two main tables. I am providing the necessary columns.

`Designers` with

```
Category | deisgnID
```

`Impressions` with

```
recId | impressionType | impressionId | impressionAction | session_id
```

Here is a sample session from the `sessions` . The `impressionId` is a polymorphic column (I think that's the term; I may be wrong) containing different data types and values.

```
recId   impressionType      impressionId    impressionAction    session_Id
73790   USER                    11182       LOGIN                   acbd1234
73791   UNDOCKED            abcd1234        UNDOCKED            acbd1234
73792   PRODUCT                 1446        TAPPED-WALL     acbd1234
73793   CARTS                   3586        ADDED           acbd1234
73794   CART-PRODUCT            14941       ADDED           acbd1234
73801   PRODUCT                 1465        TAPPED-RECOMMENDATION   acbd1234
73802   CART-PRODUCT            14942       ADDED           acbd1234
73811   PRODUCT                 1465        TAPPED-RECOMMENDATION   acbd1234
73818   PRODUCT                 1446        TAPPED-RECOMMENDATION   acbd1234
73828   PRODUCT                 1965        TAPPED-WALL     acbd1234
73829   CART-PRODUCT           14944        ADDED           acbd1234
73836   PRODUCT                 1952        TAPPED-WALL     acbd1234
73837   CART-PRODUCT            14945       ADDED           acbd1234
73882   PRODUCT                 502         TAPPED-WALL     acbd1234
73883   CART-PRODUCT            14949       ADDED           acbd1234
73897   CART-PRODUCT            14951       ADDED           acbd1234
73942   EMAILED_RECOMM          904         SEND            acbd1234
73943   EMAILED_RECOMM          1586        SEND            acbd1234
73944   EMAIL-NOTIFICATION  abcd@amazon.com SENDMAIL        acbd1234
```

I merged the two tables using the following code

```
SELECT
         d.category
        ,d.designId
        ,i.session_id
        ,COUNT( IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED'
                OR i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-LISTPAGE'
                OR i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-wall'
                OR i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-RECOMMENDATION') AS SCANS_total
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED', 1, NULL)) AS TAPPED
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-LISTPAGE', 1, NULL)) AS TAPPED_LISTPAGE
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-WALL', 1, NULL)) AS TAPPED_WALL
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-RECOMMENDATION', 1, NULL)) AS TAPPED_RECOMMENDATION
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'SEND', 1, NULL)) AS IS_ITEM_SENT_BY_EMAIL

    FROM
        Impressions i 
        INNER JOIN designers d 
        ON i.impressionId = d.designId

    WHERE
           i.createDate >= '2014-06-18'
        AND HOUR(i.createDate) >= 10
        AND HOUR(i.createDate) < 21
        AND i.impressionId not like '%amazon.com%'

    GROUP BY
        i.session_id, i.impressionId
    HAVING 
        SCANS_total <> 0


    ORDER BY
        d.category, i.impressionId, SCANS_total desc
```

Essentially, I am generating a list of *how many times a product is scanned through different types of scan* broken down by `Category` and `designId` *per* `session`.

My main issue has been : **I can't filter out certain email domains such as amazon.com** using the `i.impressionId not like '%amazon.com%'` query.

For each session, if the user emails, there is an email address under `impresseiondId` with the `impressionAction = SENDMAIL` and `impressionType = EMAIL-NOTIFICATION`.

I tried to filter out those sessions with a certain domain email completely from the calculations by using `where ... i.impressionId not like '%amazon.com%'`, but that doesn't work.

*Is there a way I can filter out certain email domains while doing what I am trying to do?*

Any thoughts will be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I woke up today and realized that a subquery that solve the problem. Here is the subquery I wrote to filter out the sessions; however, the query **times out** and fails.

Essentially the query generates all the sessions where the email address is of a certain domain and then I negate the existence of those sessions. *Any idea as far as how to optimize this and make this work?*

```
where i.session_id NOT IN(
            SELECT session_id from Impressions 
            where impressionId LIKE '%amazon.com%')
```

Comment: `the query is not able to pick up the impressionId like '%amazon.com%' since the query focuses on the impressionId = designId`. I'm not sure I understand what you mean but it's legal to have those 2 conditions on `impressionId`. Maybe add expected results vs current results for the example data.

Comment: let me go back and edit the question; thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: The initial query doesn't work. The subquery would have worked had it not timed out.

Answer (score 0):

I have been relentlessly trying to solve this problem, trying to come up with different solutions (see update for a failed solution).

I think I have it. Please let me know if there are ways to improve this.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT
         d.category
        ,d.designId
        ,i.session_id
        ,i.createDate

        ,d.name
        ,d.productTitle
        ,d.colors


        ,COUNT( IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED'
                OR i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-LISTPAGE'
                OR i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-wall'
                OR i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-RECOMMENDATION') AS SCANS_total
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED', 1, NULL)) AS TAPPED
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-LISTPAGE', 1, NULL)) AS TAPPED_LISTPAGE
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-WALL', 1, NULL)) AS TAPPED_WALL
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'TAPPED-RECOMMENDATION', 1, NULL)) AS TAPPED_RECOMMENDATION
        ,COUNT(IF(i.impressionAction = 'SEND', 1, NULL)) AS IS_ITEM_SENT_BY_EMAIL

    FROM
        Impressions i 
        INNER JOIN designers d 
        ON i.impressionId = d.designId

    WHERE
           i.createDate >= '2014-06-18'
        AND HOUR(i.createDate) >= 10
        AND HOUR(i.createDate) < 21

    GROUP BY
        i.session_id, i.impressionId
    HAVING 
        SCANS_total <> 0


    ORDER BY
        d.category, i.impressionId, SCANS_total desc 
    ) AS P
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
            SELECT session_id as sessionsToBeRemoved from Impressions 
            where impressionId LIKE '%amazon.com%'

            GROUP BY session_id
    ) AS U on P.session_id = U.sessionsToBeRemoved 
    WHERE U.sessionsToBeRemoved IS NULL
```